# \FPeval syntax error trunc and round

Tags: number

```
    \total

\FPeval{\q}{clip(100*trunc(\total :0))}

\q  \\

\FPeval{\total}{clip(100*\total)}

\total \\

\FPeval{\q1}{clip(\total -\q)}

\q1
```

**output**

```
1259.86
125900
125986
861      %the out put corret is 86
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you precise your question? Also, could you make your example compilable, so others can compile it and see what's wrong? It should begin with ``\documentclass{...}`` and end with ``\end{document}``.

Comment: Numbers aren't (usually) allowed in macro names, so `\q1` is invalid. Use `\qa` or `\qi` or something else.

Comment: also please post code that people can run to see the issue.  Your code fragment is relying on packages you have not mentioned, so it is not trivial to fill in the gaps to make anything that can be tested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `\FPeval{\q1}{clip(\total -\q)}` is syntactically incorrect; you're attempting to define a variable named `\q1`, but TeX heartily disagrees, because control sequence are made only

- by a single nonletter, or
- a sequence of letters.

The name `\q1` doesn't qualify. By reason of implementation, you get no error, but the line is essentially equivalent to

```
\FPeval{\q}{clip(\total -\q)}
```

and the following `\q1` prints the value of `\q`, that is, 86, and then prints 1.

Use a different name:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\begin{document}

\FPeval{\total}{1259.86}

\total

\FPeval{\q}{clip(100*trunc(\total :0))}

\q

\FPeval{\total}{clip(100*\total)}

\total

\FPeval{\qone}{clip(\total -\q)}

\qone

\end{document}
```

Actually you are allowed to save the final result of a computation in a string of characters. For instance,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\begin{document}

\FPeval{\total}{1259.86}

\total

\FPeval{\q}{clip(100*trunc(\total :0))}

\q

\FPeval{\total}{clip(100*\total)}

\total

\FPeval{q1}{clip(\total -\q)}

\FPprint{q1}

\end{document}
```

would work. Not recommended practice, actually: it's not even mentioned in the manual, as far as I can see.

Here's a different method using `expl3` and its powerful floating point module.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\spellnumber}{m}
 {
  \numberstringnum { \pokefaker_part_i:n { #1 } }
  \tl_if_empty:eF { \pokefaker_part_f:n { #1 } }
   {
    \c_space_tl point \c_space_tl
    \numberstringnum { \pokefaker_part_f:n { #1 } }
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IPart}{m}
 {
  \pokefaker_part_i:n { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\FPart}{m}
 {
  \pokefaker_part_f:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_range:nnn { e }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n { e } { T,F,TF,p }

\cs_new:Nn \pokefaker_part_i:n
 {
  \fp_eval:n { floor(#1) }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \pokefaker_part_f:n
 {
  \tl_range:enn { \fp_eval:n { #1 - floor(#1) } } { 3 } { -1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IPart{1259.86}

\FPart{1259.86}

\spellnumber{1259.86}

\spellnumber{2*(596.48+33.45)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You don't have to know the number of decimal digits in advance. With `\tl_range:nnn` we can extract the characters from the third to the last; a floating point number is always returned with a leading `0.` if the integral part is zero. I check for emptiness of the resulting string and output the decimal part in case it is non empty; if it is missing in the result of the computation, nothing is printed.

The argument to `\spellnumber`, `\IPart` and `\FPart` can be an “fp-expression”. For instance `\spellnumber{round(pi)}` will print “three point fourteen”.

This could be extended to cope with negative numbers as well.

It's not difficult to localize this for different languages.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\providecommand{\decimalseparatorword}{point}
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\decimalseparatorword}{virgola}}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\decimalseparatorword}{coma}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\spellnumber}{m}
 {
  \numberstringnum { \pokefaker_part_i:n { #1 } }
  \tl_if_empty:eF { \pokefaker_part_f:n { #1 } }
   {
    \c_space_tl \decimalseparatorword \c_space_tl
    \numberstringnum { \pokefaker_part_f:n { #1 } }
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IPart}{m}
 {
  \pokefaker_part_i:n { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\FPart}{m}
 {
  \pokefaker_part_f:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_range:nnn { e }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n { e } { T,F,TF,p }

\cs_new:Nn \pokefaker_part_i:n
 {
  \fp_eval:n { floor(#1) }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \pokefaker_part_f:n
 {
  \tl_range:enn { \fp_eval:n { #1 - floor(#1) } } { 3 } { -1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IPart{1259.86}

\FPart{1259.86}

\spellnumber{1259.86}

\spellnumber{2*(596.48+33.45)}

\selectlanguage{italian}

\IPart{1259.86}

\FPart{1259.86}

\spellnumber{1259.86}

\spellnumber{2*(596.48+33.45)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. |Use a different name = now work |      perfect